# Dot syntax after module name

Tags: syntax, reason

There are loads of examples of syntax similar to the below example

```
Json.Encode.(object_([("type", string(m.type_)), ("label", string(m.label))]))
```

How is this different from calling `Json.Encode.object_(([("type", string(m.type_)), ("label", string(m.label))]))` and when would I use one syntax or the other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax `M.( expr )` locally open the module M inside the expression `expr`. In other words, it brings in scope all elements of `Module` in the expression.
For instance, in your case

```
Json.Encode.(object_([("type", string(m.type_)), ("label", string(m.label))]))
```

translates to

```
Json.Encode.object_([
  ("type", Json.Encode.string(m.type_)),
  ("label", Json.Encode.string(m.label))
 ])
```

This local open syntax can be quite very useful when dealing with DSL like the one introduced by Json.Encoding while still making clear where the items introduced by the local open are being used. Contrarily, with explicit qualification of module (`Json.Encode.string`), the syntax may be heavier but the origin of each entity is clearer.

Another compromise often used is to give short aliases to frequently used modules:

```
 module Enc = Json.Encode;
 Enc.object_([
  ("type", Enc.string(m.type_)),
  ("label", Enc.string(m.label))
 ])
```